# Android form submission directly to google doc

Tags: android, spreadsheet

basically i m trying to build an android application which shows schedule of buses for to and from my campus..the problem is i have nowhere to save my data ..can i save my data from my form directly to google doc spreadsheet..if yes then how??
my xml code for form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity51" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/Outpass"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="28sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@string/Bus"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="15"
    android:inputType="number" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:ems="15"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="@string/Room"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="@string/Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/ID"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="@string/Time2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="@string/Save" />
```

now i want my data from above fields should get saved directly on google doc spreadsheet on button's onclick.
java code is:
        package com.example.sbapis1;

```
      import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;

         public class MainActivity51 extends Activity {
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity41);

}

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure  what you are trying to do. Are you trying to check out the schedules from your application or from your Google Doc Spreadsheet ?

If you are just having this spreadsheet to feed your application you would probably be better off with a SQLite implementation.

If you want the Google Spreadsheet you're going to have to use the GData library and possibly some kind of Google authentication (unless you don't mind putting your username and password directly into your app, which I wouldn't recommend). It's a lot to explain and to show code for in one post but you can check out this resource : https://github.com/gregriggins36/to-google-spreadsheet